# How to record audio from voice channel in discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I managed to create a `AudioReceiveStream` but have no idea how to pipe this to a mp3 file or how to read this stream.

This is my code so far:

```js
// Import the discord.js voice module
const voiceModule = require('@discordjs/voice');

async function voiceListener(interaction) {
    // Get voice connection
    const connection = voiceModule.getVoiceConnection(interaction.guildId);
    const listener = new voiceModule.AudioReceiveStream();
}
```

How do I get audio from the stream then write it to a mp3 file?